# How to print hex table with loops?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to print a hex table I though using this:

```
for i in range(0,1,1):
    for j in range(0,1,1):
        for k in range (0,1,1):
            for m in range (0,1,1):
                print(i,j,k,m)
```

But I only get this

```
0000
```

I think is (start,end,step) so (0,1,1) is fine or is because iterable is already consumed or what?

Comment: End value is not included to counter of a cycle.  i,j,k never reach 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`range(0,1,1)` iterates from 0 up to *but not including* 1; that is, it only has a single value (0).  So you have 4 nested loops, each of which only has 1 iteration: hence the `0000`.

Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh thanks people. Yes, now work with this:

```
for i in range(0,2):
    for j in range(0,2):
        for k in range (0,2):
            for m in range(0, 2):
                print(i,j,k,m)
```

Got his output:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0
0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0
0 1 1 1
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 1
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 0
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
```